# Should I install blog on subdomain or subdirectory?

Tags: directory, blog, subdomains

Which is better? If I install it on a subdirectory how do I go about doing that? Create a subfolder named blog and install a new copy of wordpress to that? My site currently uses wordpress, so I am not sure how this would work out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do either pretty easily or you could create a custom post type within your current installation and then you wouldn't have to do either and you would only have one installation to manage.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score -1):

I would install it as a subdomain. You can then access it by either going to subdomain.mysite.com or mysite.com/subdomain Installation will be the same as installing in the root folder. You would create the subdomain/folder and copy the wordpress files to that.